# Python Nuitka exe file not working on windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

I extracted my project as an exe file with nuitka. The file works in Windows 10, but I get the following error in Windows 7. How do I fix it? I don't know where I made a mistake

```
e 180, in <module pyautogui>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"
line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\pyscreeze\__init__.py", lin- e 10, in <module pyscreeze>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"
line 1149, in __find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\ONEFIL~1\subprocess.py", line 58, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>' line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1080, in _find_spec File "<frozen importlib. bootstrap_external", line 1504, in find_spec File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>" line 1473, in _get_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1439, in _path_importer_ca che
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1415, in _path_hooks File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1700, in path_hook_for_Fil eFinder
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1570, in _init. File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 176, in _path_isabs
SystemError: Negative size passed to PyUnicode_New
```

Comment: Please don't tag both [tag:python-3.x] and [tag:python-2.7]. Which version of Python are you actually using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your python version to <3.9 . If you are using two python versions at the same time, make sure to use `py -3.9 -m command-to-make-exe`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).